# What is the ambience space of the Lp spaces and what topology does it have?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

When we say that the $L^p$ space is complete and hence closed, what ambience space is it closed in, and what is the topology of that ambience space? I think it's the space of measurable functions, but is there a natural norm/topology on the space of measurable functions?

**An Update After Reading the Comments:**

I realized that this might just be a simple topology question rather than $L^p$ spaces. This is what I have gathered: If we view $L^p$ itself as the ambience space with the $L^p$ norm topology, then of course it is closed (closed and open at the same time) in itself. Completeness has nothing to do with closedness of the space in this case. On the other hand, if we can embed $L^p$ into any topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ and if we can show the $L^p$ norm topology is the same as the induced subspace topology of $L^p \subseteq X$, then $(L^p, \| \cdot \|_{L^p}) \subseteq (X, \mathcal{T})$ must be closed in $(X, \mathcal{T})$ as it is complete.

I suppose a question that I have not been able to figure out still is : We know $L^p$ must be embedded in the space of measurable functions. Is there a natural topology that we can put on the space of measurable functions, so that the induced subspace topology of $L^p$ is exactly the same topology as the $L^p$ norm, without knowing if the function domain is finite measure or not?

Comment: Can you give a citation for some source which says that $L^p$ is "closed"?

Comment: If $X$ is any space such that $\mathscr{L}^p$ is a (normed) subspace, then $\mathscr{L}^p$ will be closed there.

Comment: Completeness doesn't care about any ambient space, it is an intrinsic property of a metric space. $L^p$ is actually usually not closed when put into a typical ambient space other than itself; for example $L^p([0,1])$ is a non-closed subspace of $L^q([0,1])$ if $q<p$.

Comment: Usually $L_p$ is a short hand for $L_p(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ where $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ (the ambient space) is a measure space and $L_p$ is the set of numerical $\mathscr{F}$-measurable functions for which $\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu<\infty$. The ambient space may not have any structure (metric, topological or even algebraic). For $p\geq1$, $\|f\|_p=\Big(\int|f|^p\,d\mu\Big)^{1/p}$ defines a pseudonorm. When functions that are equal $\mu$-almost surely are identified, the norm $\|f\|_p$ is actually a complete norm. For $0<p<1$, $d(f,g)=\int|f-g|^p\,d\mu$ defines a complete pseudo-metric.

Comment: @OliverDíaz The question was about the ambient topological space where you are embedding $L^p$ to make it closed.

Comment: All the $L_p$ functions spaces are included in the space $L_0$ of measurable functions. If the ambient space $X$ has finite measure, then $L_0$ admits a metric $d_0(f,g)=\int|\min\{1,|f-g|\}\, d\mu$ that is complete.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I have updated my question and I wonder if the question now is more sensible?

Comment: Other than something stupid, like simply isolating $L^p$ from the rest of the space, I think the answer is no, even when you assume the space has finite measure.